# Magento 2.3.5 adding custom product attribute

Tags: product-attribute, price, custom-attributes, product-prices

I want to add a custom product attribute. Of the attribute is enabled (should only contain yes or no) if it’s enabled I want to change the price to coming soon if it’s disabled show the price.

Comment: you need to use hide price extension for that

Comment: Why do I need a extension for that @JigsParmar  I am sure it won’t be that bad. I wanted to know if I am using a plaguing or a observer to change the price.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use plugin for the class

Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox

to change the pricehtml